# Is there any way to manually add a "package" (eg. Python) to a group?

Tags: command-line, permissions, python

I've made a Python script that basically holds the account information for a special account I use on Reddit. All's fine and dandy, until I realized that, even though the folder is hidden, users etc. can still technically see and get to the directory if they go there manually or something along the lines of it (eg. viewing the files I used for the script in plain text by doing `gedit /path/to/.hidden`).

I tried getting around this by simply making `root` the primary owner and the only one who can view **that specific folder**, emphasized so that people don't think I locked myself out of main home folders, but the issue now is that Python can't view the files needed because it has no read access.

Would there be any possible way to add Python to its own group, similarly to what Virtualbox does automatically when you set it up (eg. so I can do something along the lines of `sudo chown python:python /path/to/files`)? If not, are there any alternatives to prevent snooping, but to still allow Python to view and read the files?

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 (and if it helps any, I've got installed and have mainly been using the MATE Desktop environment.)

Comment: Who should be able to run script? All users, or your admin user?

Comment: ((I edited the question with my Ubuntu version.)) I'm the only user account on the system, so either one would work.

Comment: What I don't want is, even though I'm the only user account, anyone on my PC to see the files the script reads to verify everything, since for simplicity the account info for Reddit is in plain text. (Snooping people in my household who enjoy snooping.)

Comment: If your problem is snooping people, lock your computer when you are away from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, fundamentally not. You want the user to be able to read the file, via the python command, but not check the content of the file.

First of all, from technical perspective, it *could* be possible if you make python a setuid binary (Note: don't do this; this will probably break other parts of your system). But. Python is not made for that.

I can start python with `python -i script`:

> ```
> -i        When  a  script  is passed as first argument or the -c option is
>           used, enter interactive mode after executing the script  or  the
>           command.  It does not read the $PYTHONSTARTUP file.  This can be
>           useful to inspect global variables  or  a  stack  trace  when  a
>           script raises an exception.
> ```

This basically means that I can access **all** variables and methods in your script freely. I can modify the behavior of the script. If it logs into reddit, I can acquire the authentication tokens, and sign in using a browser. It would probably be possible to retrieve the password as well.

I could even write a small python script, that reads your script, line by line, and prints it back to me. Python ***cannot*** be made safe for setuid, because it's a full featured programming language. If you allow python to read the file, you allow **any** user that can run python to read the file.

The problem is fundamentally that you are trying to hide the information from the user. However, to perform the intended function, the user requires this information. That's an unsolvable problem.

Comment: While the theoreticals you go into are definitely things to consider should I try to hide larger scale whatevers, the people I don't want being able to view the info aren't as... technologically advanced, for lack of a better term, to do the thingns you said (eg. creating a script to print the script). I don't even know if they could use ``gedit /path/to/.hidden", honestly. What I know is they know how to go to "View" and then check "Show hidden files".

Comment: Lock your computer when you are not using it. Create a separate account for any other user of the computer. Trying to cobble up your own schemes is security through obscurity, and essentially adds complexity without any real gain.

Comment: On the other hand, making Python a setuid binary and bricking my system? Probably not a good idea. Are there any alternatives that I could potentially use?

Comment: Fair enough lol, I was just being a little over-protective and trying to be as many steps ahead as I could. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Being ahead in this situation is not trying to dream up your own schemes. It's using what the system provides: file access permissions and different user accounts. It's fairly well tested, and problems gets patched *fast* because many people rely on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can make new user, make it ownership of script, and disable all others access to script(0700 permissions)
To run script use sudo command as follows, so you have to type password everytime and that makes a bit of security.

```
sudo -u newuser python /path/to/.hidden
```

Update: To hide newuser from login page make it uid below 1000, and set shell to /bin/false so not allowing login anyway, but still possible to sudo as this user

Comment: Thanks for the alternative! I marked vidarlo's answer as best because he goes into detail about the dangers (and on a larger scale ambiguity) of my request, but I like this omen too as it's a slightly lesser complex version of what I need done.